# Why Not operator for negative number gives this output

Tags: c

Can somebody please explain output of below code-

```
int a =-3;
printf("%d",!a);
```

The output is `0`.
I cannot understand why i get output as `0`.

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: If you don't understand that, you have to study what the `!` operator does, simple as that. And also study other utterly fundamental things like how an `if` statement works. This site isn't an interactive beginner tutorial replacing studies.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.5.3.3

> *The result of the logical negation operator `!` is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type `int`. The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.*

In your case, it can be seen as

```
 printf("%d", (a == 0));   // where a is -3
```

which evaluates to a falsy result, thereby printing `0` as the result.